# Creating .json file and storing data in it with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a back-end `JavaScript` file that runs on `node.js`. It do some stuff using `async.series` and yields the final dictionary(object) with data I need on my front-end. I now how to read a `.json` file and convert it into the `JavaScript` object, but I do not know create `.json` file with back-end `JavaScript` and how to store some data in it.

Could anyone please tell me the right way to do this.

Here is the dictionary(object) that I need to convert and store to the `.json` file.

```
var dict = {"one" : [15, 4.5],
            "two" : [34, 3.3],
            "three" : [67, 5.0],
            "four" : [32, 4.1]};
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simple! You can convert it to a JSON (as a string).

```
var dictstring = JSON.stringify(dict);
```

To save a file in NodeJS:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("thing.json", dictstring);
```

Also, objects in javascript use colons, not equals:

```
var dict = {"one" : [15, 4.5],
        "two" : [34, 3.3],
        "three" : [67, 5.0],
        "four" : [32, 4.1]};
```

Comment: ok, but how can I create `.json` file and store this `string` into it?

Comment: Check the answer now, should be ok

Comment: tnx but fs.writeFile(...) requires a third (or fourth) parameter which is a callback function to be invoked when the operation completes.

Comment: @ashkannasirzadeh this is right. I just edited this answer so it can work fine.

Answer (score 17):

1- make your obj:

```
var dict = {"one" : [15, 4.5],
    "two" : [34, 3.3],
    "three" : [67, 5.0],
    "four" : [32, 4.1]};
```

2- make it JSON:

```
var dictstring = JSON.stringify(dict);
```

3- save your json file and **dont forget** that `fs.writeFile(...)` requires a third (or fourth) parameter which is a callback function to be invoked when the operation completes.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("thing.json", dictstring, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

Comment: But then how do you generate a json file output

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer, I was getting invalid callback error. probably an old version of fs worked without the callback