# How to create a .json File in React.js with data in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app and I want to create JSON files for my react application dynamically.

I searched up and found an answer on how to create JSON files in node.js with the fs module. Link: [Creating .json file and storing data in it with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590486/creating-json-file-and-storing-data-in-it-with-javascript)

That module can't be used in React.

So I need help

Thanks

Comment: React runs in the browser, and as such has no access to the local file system. You could offer the JSON data as a download to the user, but right after that the file is not reachable from React anymore.

Comment: for what u want to create a json file? To cache responses etc? Their are better solutions for that like `redux-persist` or the native Browser Storages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download JSON object as a file from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800715/13255493)

Comment: ya this does answer my question